# How do I structure a menu containing introductory elements?

Tags: html, structure

How is the best way of structuring content with introductory elements that have an ambiguous relation to the overall hierarchy? I think it's best illustrated with an example (example 1):

```
<main>
  <h1>Menu</h1>
  <h2>Concept</h2>
  <!-- A description of the concept -->
  <h2>Prices</h2>
  <!-- A price list -->
  <h2>Meat</h2>
  <h2>Vegetarian</h2>
  <h2>Desserts</h2>
</main>
```

Here *Concept* and *Prices* is natural as introductory elements, but hierarchically I don't feel they belong on the same level as *Meat*, *Vegetarian* and *Desserts*.

Perhaps it's better to place the introductory elements in an aside-element? Like this (example 2):

```
<main>
  <h1>Menu</h1>
  <aside>
    <h2>Concept</h2>
    <!-- A description of the concept -->
    <h2>Prices</h2>
    <!-- A price list -->
  </aside>
  <h2>Meat</h2>
  <h2>Vegetarian</h2>
  <h2>Desserts</h2>
</main>
```

I'm not sure this is the proper usage of the aside-element. What about putting it in a header, and perhaps also sectioning the whole thing (example 3):

```
<main>
  <header>
    <h1>Menu</h1>
    <h2>Concept</h2>
    <!-- A description of the concept -->
    <h2>Prices</h2>
    <!-- A price list -->
  </header>
  <section>
    <h1>Meat</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Vegetarian</h1>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1>Desserts</h1>
  </section>
</main>
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on this? Perhaps none of my examples are right, in that case I'd like to know what's the best practice for structuring this type of content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is a very general question. my subjective opinion is to get this structure. Avoid of using more than one H1 on one page. section tag is used to mark areas of connected information. article is used to one item from some list, which has complete meaning (can stand alone). sections and articles should always have a title

```
<main>
  <header>
    <h1>Menu</h1>
  </header>
  <section>
    <h2>Concept</h2>
    <!-- A description of the concept -->
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Prices</h2>
    <!-- A price list -->
  </section>
  <section>
    <h2>Meal types</h2>
    <article>
      <h3>Meat</h3>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>Vegetarian</h3>
    </article>
    <article>
      <h3>Desserts</h3>
    </article>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Ok, this might be more up to personal taste than I thought. I do believe that h1-tags may be used again inside section and article tags though.